# How to fetch the size of generic map in typescript 2.8.3

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on application that runs on Angular 2.4 and Typescript 2.8.3. I have defined a generic map and want to know the size of map after adding/removing certain elements.

```js
let map  = new Map<String, String>();
...
```

Here `map.size()` throws error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature typescript. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures. ts(2349)

I also tried below snippet but it always returns `0` even if map has elements defined!

```js
Objects.keys(map).length // 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map.size` is a property that returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size), it's not a function.

```
let map  = new Map<String, String>();
console.log(map.size); //-> 0
```

The error tells you this, in verbose sort of way.

> *Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures*

This means you have a `Number` and you are trying `call` it with `()`. `Number` cannot be called, because the types for number do not specify a signature for invocation. From this you can infer that the value before your `()` is a number, and not a function reference.

---

Also, `Object.keys(map)` will never give you the keys in a map. That will give you the properties of a map object, but not the data in the map.

To work with a map's data, you need to use [the methods defined by Map class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).